# Could not set locale for common user

Tags: locale, i3

I'm using i3wm, after an update, I run into a locale problem that doesn't let me run `i3status` correctly.

I had a major advance on this issue. Reconfigure locale on `/etc/locale.gen` and also on `/etc/default/locale`, and now when I run i3status as root, it works, but when I start the system (as my user), it throw `status_command process exited unexpectedly`.

I tried to give those files full permission `(777)`, but id doesn't work neither.

I know that the problem is almost fixed, until I run `locale-gen`, and `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, as soon as I opened a terminal, before the prompt it said `Could not set locale. Please make sure all your LC_* / LANG settings are correct`.

Now I only have this error when I try to run `i3status`. Any ideas about how can I recover i3wm from this issue?

When I type locale as root the file shows:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When I run it as my user it doesn't have LANGUAGE variable set:

```
LANG=es_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="es_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="es_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="es_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="es_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="es_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed! I just copy the response of running locale as root to `/etc/default/locale` and everything works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you most likely need to do in order to properly fix this problem....

1. The problem:

   ```shellsession
   [user@archlinux ~]$ i3status
   Could not set locale. Please make sure all your LC_* / LANG settings are correct.
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/locale.conf` so that it contains (at least) your chosen "locale" values for variables:

   ```shellsession
   [user@archlinux ~]$ cat /etc/locale.conf
   LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
   LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
   ```
3. Generate the locale using `locale-gen`:

   ```shellsession
   [user@archlinux ~]$ sudo locale-gen 
   Generating locales...
     en_GB.UTF-8... done
   Generation complete.
   ```
4. Test `i3status` command (should work fine)...

   ```shellsession
   [mconway@bigwig ~]$ i3status
   {"version":1}
   [
   [<DATA>]
   [<DATA>]
   ...
   ```
5. DO NOT hack stuff by doing things such as setting/overriding "system" environment variables such as `LC_ALL=C <command` (Note `LC_ALL` should only be used for troubleshooting/testing)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this problem by adding `LC_ALL=C` to the invocation of `i3status` from `.i3/config`:

what I had:

```
    status_command i3status --config ~/.i3/i3status.conf
```

what I replaced it with:

```
    status_command LC_ALL=C i3status --config ~/.i3/i3status.conf
```

Comment: This isn't a "fix" it is a workaround, and an ill-advised one at that...